# How can I get a page to display the same in Chrome and IE?

Tags: jquery, html, css, blueprint-css

SOS! I have a page that will display well in chrome, Firefox, and safari. But in Internet Explorer it looks absolutely terrible. Can anyone show me what needs to be changed so IE displays the page the same as Chrome displays it? This is probably sounding really stupid but I really need help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of issues there. A few issues I see from first glance:

1. No doctype.
2. Deprecated attributes. `bgcolor` and `align` are deprecated, there might be others.
3. Is there a reason why you're using frames there? It's effectively a new window so you have to set the background color etc in the frame, but I can't see a reason for you using frames at all.
4. You're using a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto;` on your container div to center it. Instead, you should be applying that to a div inside the container. That's why it's not centering in IE. IE is being technically correct; Webkit is compensating for the error.

There's probably more but those are the most obvious. I'd highly recommend you start this page again; begin with a modern boilerplate and build it up from there.

Comment: I figure you've fixed the textarea issue now as it looks OK.